# Convert Binary 010101 to Lat OR Long using MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Good Day,

I am fairly new to T-SQL and have the following problem that i need to resolve
i have a table with binary values in them, i need to convert them to a Lat and a Long.

```
Hemisphere LAT  Latitude            Hemisphere LONG   Longitude
 +              100010100100000011   -                0000110000001111111
 +              100010100100000100   +                0000110000001110011
 +              100010100010111101   +                0000110000010100100
```

How can i extract the lat longs from the Binary values? I have 3750 ROWS to convert to Lat Long, and was wondering if it is possible in MSSQL.

Comment: You chould specify the exact datatypes for table columns 'Latitude', 'Longitude' you use (try 'Create table..' function in SSMS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find out the way your (Lat,Long) are stored - it will depend then how to treat them right to get meaningful values.
Anyway, this could allows to transform 2-base binary value to 10-based:

```
DECLARE @Input varchar(255) = '100010100100000011'
DECLARE @Cnt tinyint = 1
    DECLARE @Len tinyint = LEN(@Input)
    DECLARE @Output bigint = CAST(SUBSTRING(@Input, @Len, 1) AS bigint)

    WHILE(@Cnt < @Len) BEGIN
        SET @Output = @Output + POWER(CAST( 
               SUBSTRING(@Input, @Len - @Cnt, 1) * 2 AS bigint), @Cnt)    
        SET @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
    END
select @Output
--------------
141571
```

Also, I suppose [this article](http://improve.dk/converting-between-base-2-10-and-16-in-t-sql/) would be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

If the binary values are of Geometry type you can do this:

```
SELECT 
   Geometry.Lat as [Latitude],
   Geometry.Long as [Longitude]
FROM dbo.tbl
```